# Почему не возвращает результат запроса

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Скрипт должен запросить данные с сайта, и после этого вернуть их.

Я сделал такой script.js

```
console.log( getLinks() );

async function getLinks() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/data.php');
    const array_usrls = response.data;
    return array_usrls;
}
```

после запуска скрипта

> node script

я получаю `Promise { <pending> }`

вероятно нужно как-то дождаться выполнения...

Просьба поправить мой код. И простите если это очень глупо, я только начинаю работать с Node JS и javascript

Comment: `console.log( await getLinks() );` или `getLinks().then(console.log)`

Comment: чтобы использовать `await getLinks()` надо предварительно обернуть в асинхронную функцию: `(async() => { console.log(await getLinks()) })()`;

Comment: @entithat большое спасибо!

Comment: @entithat просьба пояснить разницу `(async() => { console.log(await getLinks()) })()` и `(async() => { console.log(await getLinks()) })` - во втором случае ничего не вывело на экран

Comment: Второй вариант не содержит в конце`()`, что значит, что эта анонимная функция будет вызываться на месте и соответственно, она не будет выполнять свой внутренний код